# How to make changes of config under /etc folder to take effect?

Tags: server, configuration, etc

I'm a rookie in Ubuntu and recently trying to learn Ubuntu. Now I encountered a very serious issue that for some reasons I need to update the configuration file like httpd.conf, hosts.deny and others and in order to make these changes to take effect, every time I rebooted the Ubutn server machine which is totally not allowed and produces serious impacts. I know Ubuntu has many kinds of configuation files, including ones from system itself, or user's applications, etc, so the questions I'm intending to ask are:

1, can anybody summarize a list of types of configuation files in Ubuntu?

2, what's the convenient way for making these changes to take effect without rebooting the machine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For changes maded on our own application's configuation file, I know how to take it effect, just restart the application.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the service, but in most cases involves `sudo service <service name> reload`:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
sudo service squid3 reload
sudo service sshd reload
```

In the case that the operation returns:

```
$ sudo service motd reload
Error: argument 'reload' not supported
```

You can try `restart`.

```
sudo service motd restart
```

If that don't work too, then a combination of `stop` and `start`:

```
sudo service motd stop
sudo service motd start
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sometimes, I just fix a bug and I don't know what the service the configuration file belongs to. In this case what do I do?

Comment: Well for many things manpages are useful. Try for example man deny.conf. This does not work for every file, but for nearly every service. Config-files to a service are most probably listed there. To search reverse (file->service) try something like google or duckduckgo.com to search for the file path and name to gather information.

Answer (score 1):

Some changes take effect immediately, because the /etc file is consulted each time it is needed. For example, if you update /etc/hosts (or in the example you give, /etc/hosts.deny), it is effective immediately because next time the contents are needed the file is re-read.

If you know the service related to the config file, then reload or restart the service - see Braiam's comprehensive answer.

If you don't know which service the file relates do, then perhaps you should not be editing it? :-)

One option is to look at the list of available services and take a guess. The `service` command invoked init.d scripts, so

```
$ ls /etc/init.d
```

will give you the list of services.

Another option is to find which package the config file belongs to. Ask `dpkg`:

```
# dpkg -S /etc/ntp.conf
ntp: /etc/ntp.conf
```

This tells me that /etc/ntp.conf belongs to the ntp package - and sure enough there is a ntp service that can be reloaded or restarted.